# Multiple kernels in grub

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I like to have some kernels in my system, just in case an update breaks something. I had to change one option in order to have multiple kernels and choose one of them every time i start the computer.

I dont remember where this option is. I want to say how many kernels can my system save. ( ex: the update kernel and three older kernels). Ive been googleing and i cant locate that option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you arrive at `grub`, you will get some options like 
`Ubuntu` 
`Advanced Options for Ubuntu`
`Memory Tests` etc...
when you click on second option (`Advanced options for Ubuntu`), we'll get last 4 latest Linux kernels.And respective additional kernels that will load in `recovery mode`.

Comment: I thought it was an option to configure that 4 number of kernels somewhere...and to enable/disable this option of MULTI KERNEL Thanks for your help